# Install MongoDB Management Service on ARM

Tags: mongodb, arm

Is it possible to install MongoDB Management Service on single-board computer with ARM architecture? In official web site has articles only for x86_64 and i386, but nothing about ARM.

Comment: Which board you are using ?

Comment: Only MongoDB can answer that question since MMS and its agents are closed source

Comment: Note: The on-premise version of MMS is a commercial product available as part of a [subscription agreement](http://www.mongodb.com/subscription-agreement/August-2014) which you agree to as part of downloading a trial version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM isn't a supported platform for MongoDB (as at MongoDB 3.0).

Ops Manager (the on-premise version of MMS) is also intended for server-class computers with minimum hardware spec well above a 32-bit CPU with 1Gb of RAM (multiple cores, 16Gb of RAM).

For more information on the current state of ARM support in the MongoDB Server, see [SERVER-1811](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811?focusedCommentId=680707&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-680707) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a community working on MongoDB version >= 3.0 in **Arch Linux** distro. The newest version 3.0.7 MongoDB doesn't work, but the version **3.0.4** does! I tried myself and it works! For 32bits (armv7) the support database size is limited to 2 GBs.